# What is the best way to store loose tea to maintain its freshness?

Tags: storage-method, tea

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AI87X0O) is the tea I use. Like Coffee needs to be stored in freezer, are there any storage restrictions for loose tea leaves also?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tea needs to be kept away from heat, light, air, and moisture. The best way to store tea is at room temperature in an opaque, airtight container.

Your container should not be plastic, because odors from previous uses (even if its only been used solely for tea) could contaminate your current tea.

Do not store tea in the freezer or refrigerator. Opening and closing of the door causes rapid humidity changes that cause moisture to seep into the container and degrade the flavor of the tea.

Some cheap tea containers can be found here: http://www.specialtybottle.com/teatincontainersmi.aspx

Personally, I would go for one with a twist or latching cover rather than a slip cover, just to ensure that it's airtight.

**References**

- http://www.uptontea.com/shopcart/information/INFOstoring.asp
- http://www.teavana.com/tea-info/tea-storage-for-loose-leaf-teas
- http://www.teavivre.com/info/proper-storage-of-tea.html
- http://verdanttea.com/how-to-store-tea/

Comment: `Do not store tea in the freezer or refrigerator.` - reasons?

Comment: "Moisture is equally detrimental to fragile tea leaves. Like any organic matter, tea, when wet, begins to mold and decay—a wholly undesirable effect. For this reason, we do not recommend storing tea in the refrigerator or freezer because continual opening and closing of the door causes rapid changes in humidity. Modern freezers cycle through different temperatures and often create an icing problem. Moisture seeps into the container and robs the tea leaves of flavor."

http://www.uptontea.com/shopcart/information/INFOstoring.asp

Edit: edited answer to add succinct clarification

Answer (score 5):

I use a tin that some posh tea came in.  The lid fits pretty tight.

But anything airtight should do; a decent tupperware box or even a jam jar or a sauce bottle.  I used to keep flour, sugar and everything in them when I was a student because the places I lived were always damp.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way is if you take the tea into a hermetically sealed box (that can be found in almost every supermarket), the tea won't lose their smell and taste in a long time. But don't forget everything will go bad sooner or later.

The freezing isn't recommended, because the micro ice cristalls do harm the fibers of the foods, that's why the freezing makes more tastles the frozen foods (but not very much).
This is the reason why the meets can be frozen only once.

Comment: I didn't want to copy the above answer.
When I wrote my answer, I didn't see what Wayfaring Stranger had wrotten.

Answer (score 2):

You must buy teas from some reputed shops .It should be placed in a very dry place with out any strong smells.Green tea requires more preservation than other teas If you keep it with vacuum sealer then it will be preserved for more days.
You can also see some different tea preservation process here:-http://www.teanaga.com/learn-about-tea/how-to-store-different-kinds-of-tea/

Answer (score 1):

Keep it sealed under low light. If you can smell the tea, it's losing flavor. For large quantities I use 1L widemouth jars with screw on plastic lids. Plastic gives a tighter seal than metal for this sort of thing.